# Why does it matter where fopen is used?

Tags: c, file, fopen

I could use some help understanding something puzzling to me. It concerns the position of of fopen() to read out a file.

Following code (C compiled with gcc 4.5.2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void try_fopen(FILE* f_handle, const char* f_name, const char* mode) {
    f_handle = fopen(f_name, mode);
    if( f_handle == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open '%s'.", f_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int cnt_ones(FILE* pFile) {
    int c;
    int n = 0;

    do {
      c = fgetc (pFile);
      if (c == '1') n++;
    } while (c != EOF);

    return n;
}
```

Why is it that putting the fopen in a function gives a Segfault:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE * pFile;
    try_fopen(pFile, argv[1], "r"); // Gives a Segfault

    printf ("The file contains %d ones.\n", cnt_ones(pFile) );
    fclose (pFile);

    return 0;
}
```

While putting it into the main (along with the if doesn't):

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // While this doesn't give a Segfault
    if( pFile == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open '%s'.", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("The file contains %d sign characters.\n", cnt_ones(pFile) );
    fclose (pFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the FILE* pointer is passed by value? Either return the pointer, or use a double pointer.

Comment: I see now, the errors of my ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is pass by value, not by reference, so you need to pass the pointer to `pFile`, otherwise you don't change it outside of the function scope:

```
void try_fopen(FILE** f_handle, const char* f_name, const char* mode) {
    *f_handle = fopen(f_name, mode);
    if( *f_handle == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open '%s'.", f_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// ...
try_fopen(&pFile, argv[1], "r");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the pointer `pFile` is passed by value to the function `try_open`. The value modified inside the function is not available in the `main`. To solve this, you need to pass the address of the pointer to the function, so `try_open` would accept `FILE**` and assign the result of `fopen` to `*pFile`. While calling this function you should pass the address of `pFile` using `&pFile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do :

```
File * fp;
try_fopen( &fp,.....); /* void try_fopen (FILE ** fp,....) */
```

or the following :

```
File * fp = try_fopen("file name"); /* FILE * try_fopen (const char * file_name,...) */
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple, when you pass FILE* to function, it's updation will be lost as it is passed by Value. Try passing FILE ** to the function and it will work. Refer to Binyamin Sharet's answer above for the code snippet

The reason for this can be understood by reading this [link](http://geeki.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/is-c-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/)

Or

You can change the function try_open to return FILE * as the return value.

```
FILE *try_fopen(const char* f_name, const char* mode) 
{ 
   FILE *f_handle = NULL;    
  *f_handle = fopen(f_name, mode);     
   if( *f_handle == NULL ) 
   {         
     fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open '%s'.", f_name);         
     exit(0);     
   } 
} 

  //In the main function.
  FILE *pFile = try_fopen(argv[1], "r");
```